# Borrow iOS native camera app into my own app

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios-camera

I have an idea of creating a custom `iOS` camera app that could extend the camera's use. First of all I am thinking to just "borrow" or integrate the entire functions and `UI` of the native `iOS` camera app into my own app, for which means when I use my app to take a picture, the `UI` would be exactly same as when I open the camera app and I can use it to switch between taking a **picture, recording videos, taking squares, panos, SLO-MO**... you name it.

Is there any way that we could do that? Is there any api or library or any import I can use to inject into my code? Any great tutorials about **`iOS` camera apps**?

New to `Swift`. Appreciate it everybody!

[Ps: Image is just used to clarify... borrowed from Apple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeBHi.png)

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing is using [UIImagePickerController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller), unfortunately when you use this component provided by Apple you have no mean of modifying the behaviors as long as the Camera View Controller is presented.
This API is provided as an help to easily integrate camera functionality into your app.

If you want to customize the interface and make new functionalities you have to make it yourself using AV Foundation framework as stated by Apple in `UIImagePickerController` documentation.

> To perform fully-customized image or movie capture, instead use the AV Foundation framework as described in Still and Video Media Capture. Camera access using the AV Foundation framework is available starting in iOS 4.0.

Comment: Thanks for your help Fantattitude! I'm working on it :D!